# How can I easily remove lines that matches some regular expression from lastly modified files

Tags: ruby, git

I am new to Ruby and I often do the debugging with this [tool](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug). It requires to put this line on a place of the breakpoint

```
binding.pry
```

Then in the console I am able to debug. I don't want other solution, I am ok with that. But my code is often polluted with those lines that I need to get rid of before doing the commit. Is there any way that will check if a file contains this line and if yes, it'd delete it? Some git + sed magic I guess, or is there something built in git?

Comment: Discover [`rubocop`](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop).

Comment: Sounds like something you could use a `pre-commit` for. [Link](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Comment: @mudasobwa could you be more specific than "rubocop". I am already using it, but I see no link between my answer and static analysis tool.

Comment: It could be github precommit hook, as @Fairy suggested ( e.g. [overcommit hook](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit) that makes use of `rubocop`,) or you might simply run `rubocop` and it will report all occurrences of `binding.pry`.

Comment: Please read the question again. It says "How can I easily _remove_" ... not "How can I easily discover.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came up with

```
sed -i -e '/binding\.pry/d' `git diff-index --name-only -G "binding\.pry" HEAD`
```

This works perfectly for my needs.

Comment: I would add that if you're working on MacOS you must add a zero-length extension to the `-i` parameter like so `-i ''` for it to work as expected.